# How to create an Expr that evaluates to Expr in Julia?

Tags: julia, metaprogramming

I have a variable `ex` that represents an Expr, I want to have a function `exprwrap` that creates an Expr from it which when evaluated is equal to `ex`.

Currently I implement it as follows:

```
ex = :(my + expr)

"Make an expression that when evaled returns the input ex."
function exprwrap(ex::Expr)
  ret = :(:(du + mmy))
  ret.args[1] = ex
  ret
end

eval(exprwrap(ex)) == ex
```

Keep in mind that `my` and `expr` are not defined so `:(:($$ex))` does not do the job.

What is a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write:

```
Expr(:quote, x)
```

or

```
Expr(:block, ex)
```

or

```
:($ex;)
```

Additionally you could do:

```
Meta.parse(":($ex)")
```

which is not simple but shows you how Julia parses `ex` when it appears in the source code and you can see that it is the same as `Expr(:quote, ex)`.

Similarly yo can check that `Meta.parse("($ex;)") == Expr(:block, ex)`.

Comment: There is also `Meta.quot` which is evaluates to `Expr(:quote, x)` too.